# Received more than 8 bytes decoding i64. Was an expression of a different type misidentified as BigInteger

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

when I using i64 to recive the sum result of rust diesel like this:

```
pub fn get_bill_book_account_sum(request: &BillAccountRequest) -> Result<Vec<(i64, i32)>, diesel::result::Error>{
    use crate::diesel::GroupByDsl;
    use crate::model::diesel::fortune::fortune_schema::bill_record as bill_record_table;
    let source_query = bill_record_table::table
        .group_by(bill_record_table::account_id)
        .select((diesel::dsl::sql::<diesel::sql_types::BigInt>("sum(amount)"),bill_record_table::account_id))
        .filter(bill_record_table::dsl::bill_book_id.eq(request.bill_book_id));
    let result = source_query.load::<(i64,i32)>(&get_connection());
    return result;
}
```

shows error like this:

```
GET /fortune/bill-book-account/v1/list?bill_book_id=9:
   >> Matched: (list) GET /fortune/bill-book-account/v1/list?<query..>
thread 'rocket-worker-thread' panicked at 'Received more than 8 bytes decoding i64. Was an expression of a different type misidentified as BigInteger?', /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/diesel-1.4.8/src/type_impls/integers.rs:68:9
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:525:12
   1: diesel::type_impls::integers::<impl diesel::deserialize::FromSql<diesel::sql_types::BigInt,DB> for i64>::from_sql
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/diesel-1.4.8/src/type_impls/integers.rs:68:9
   2: diesel::type_impls::primitives::foreign_impls::_impl_from_sql_row_for_i64proxy::<impl diesel::deserialize::FromSqlRow<__ST,__DB> for i64>::build_from_row
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/diesel-1.4.8/src/type_impls/primitives.rs:33:14
   3: diesel::type_impls::tuples::<impl diesel::deserialize::FromSqlRow<(SA,SB),__DB> for (A,B)>::build_from_row
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/diesel-1.4.8/src/type_impls/tuples.rs:57:27
   4: <diesel::pg::connection::cursor::Cursor<ST,T> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::next
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/diesel-1.4.8/src/pg/connection/cursor.rs:41:25
   5: core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator::try_fold
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:1994:29
   6: <core::iter::adapters::ResultShunt<I,E> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::try_fold
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/iter/adapters/mod.rs:178:9
   7: core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator::find
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:2463:9
   8: <core::iter::adapters::ResultShunt<I,E> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::next
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/iter/adapters/mod.rs:160:9
   9: <alloc::vec::Vec<T> as alloc::vec::spec_from_iter_nested::SpecFromIterNested<T,I>>::from_iter
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/alloc/src/vec/spec_from_iter_nested.rs:23:32
  10: <alloc::vec::Vec<T> as alloc::vec::spec_from_iter::SpecFromIter<T,I>>::from_iter
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/alloc/src/vec/spec_from_iter.rs:33:9
  11: <alloc::vec::Vec<T> as core::iter::traits::collect::FromIterator<T>>::from_iter
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:2541:9
  12: core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator::collect
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:1745:9
  13: <core::result::Result<V,E> as core::iter::traits::collect::FromIterator<core::result::Result<A,E>>>::from_iter::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/result.rs:1972:53
  14: core::iter::adapters::process_results
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/iter/adapters/mod.rs:149:17
  15: <core::result::Result<V,E> as core::iter::traits::collect::FromIterator<core::result::Result<A,E>>>::from_iter
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/result.rs:1972:9
  16: core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator::collect
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:1745:9
  17: <diesel::pg::connection::PgConnection as diesel::connection::Connection>::query_by_index::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/diesel-1.4.8/src/pg/connection/mod.rs:78:27
  18: core::result::Result<T,E>::and_then
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/result.rs:1252:22
  19: <diesel::pg::connection::PgConnection as diesel::connection::Connection>::query_by_index
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/diesel-1.4.8/src/pg/connection/mod.rs:76:9
  20: <T as diesel::query_dsl::load_dsl::LoadQuery<Conn,U>>::internal_load
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/diesel-1.4.8/src/query_dsl/load_dsl.rs:30:9
  21: diesel::query_dsl::RunQueryDsl::load
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/diesel-1.4.8/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1240:9
  22: fortune::service::bill::bill_book_account_service::get_bill_book_account_sum
             at ./src/service/bill/bill_book_account_service.rs:34:18
  23: fortune::service::bill::bill_book_account_service::get_bill_book_account_list
             at ./src/service/bill/bill_book_account_service.rs:23:18
  24: fortune::biz::bill::bill_book_account_controller::list
             at ./src/biz/bill/bill_book_account_controller.rs:30:20
  25: fortune::biz::bill::bill_book_account_controller::list::into_info::monomorphized_function::{{closure}}
             at ./src/biz/bill/bill_book_account_controller.rs:29:8
  26: <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/future/mod.rs:84:19
  27: <core::pin::Pin<P> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/future/future.rs:123:9
  28: <core::panic::unwind_safe::AssertUnwindSafe<F> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/panic/unwind_safe.rs:289:9
  29: <futures_util::future::future::catch_unwind::CatchUnwind<Fut> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/futures-util-0.3.21/src/future/future/catch_unwind.rs:36:42
  30: <core::panic::unwind_safe::AssertUnwindSafe<F> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<()>>::call_once
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/panic/unwind_safe.rs:271:9
  31: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:406:40
  32: <unknown>
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/str/iter.rs:499:14
  33: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:370:19
  34: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panic.rs:133:14
  35: <futures_util::future::future::catch_unwind::CatchUnwind<Fut> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/futures-util-0.3.21/src/future/future/catch_unwind.rs:36:9
  36: rocket::server::handle::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/rocket-0.5.0-rc.2/src/server.rs:54:24
  37: <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/future/mod.rs:84:19
  38: rocket::server::<impl rocket::rocket::Rocket<rocket::phase::Orbit>>::route::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/rocket-0.5.0-rc.2/src/server.rs:281:79
  39: <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/future/mod.rs:84:19
  40: rocket::server::<impl rocket::rocket::Rocket<rocket::phase::Orbit>>::route_and_process::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/rocket-0.5.0-rc.2/src/server.rs:236:59
  41: <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/future/mod.rs:84:19
  42: rocket::server::<impl rocket::rocket::Rocket<rocket::phase::Orbit>>::dispatch::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/rocket-0.5.0-rc.2/src/server.rs:210:65
  43: <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/future/mod.rs:84:19
  44: rocket::server::hyper_service_fn::{{closure}}::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/rocket-0.5.0-rc.2/src/server.rs:82:70
  45: <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/future/mod.rs:84:19
  46: <core::pin::Pin<P> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/future/future.rs:123:9
  47: tokio::runtime::task::core::CoreStage<T>::poll::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/core.rs:165:17
  48: tokio::loom::std::unsafe_cell::UnsafeCell<T>::with_mut
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/loom/std/unsafe_cell.rs:14:9
  49: tokio::runtime::task::core::CoreStage<T>::poll
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/core.rs:155:13
  50: tokio::runtime::task::harness::poll_future::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/harness.rs:470:19
  51: <core::panic::unwind_safe::AssertUnwindSafe<F> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<()>>::call_once
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/panic/unwind_safe.rs:271:9
  52: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:406:40
  53: <unknown>
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:434:6
  54: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:370:19
  55: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panic.rs:133:14
  56: tokio::runtime::task::harness::poll_future
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/harness.rs:458:18
  57: tokio::runtime::task::harness::Harness<T,S>::poll_inner
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/harness.rs:104:27
  58: tokio::runtime::task::harness::Harness<T,S>::poll
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/harness.rs:57:15
  59: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/raw.rs:144:5
  60: tokio::runtime::task::raw::RawTask::poll
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/raw.rs:84:18
  61: tokio::runtime::task::LocalNotified<S>::run
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/mod.rs:376:9
  62: tokio::runtime::thread_pool::worker::Context::run_task::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/thread_pool/worker.rs:458:21
  63: tokio::coop::with_budget::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/coop.rs:102:9
  64: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::try_with
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:412:16
  65: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:388:9
  66: tokio::coop::with_budget
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/coop.rs:95:5
  67: tokio::coop::budget
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/coop.rs:72:5
  68: tokio::runtime::thread_pool::worker::Context::run_task
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/thread_pool/worker.rs:434:9
  69: tokio::runtime::thread_pool::worker::Context::run
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/thread_pool/worker.rs:401:24
  70: tokio::runtime::thread_pool::worker::run::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/thread_pool/worker.rs:386:17
  71: tokio::macros::scoped_tls::ScopedKey<T>::set
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/macros/scoped_tls.rs:61:9
  72: tokio::runtime::thread_pool::worker::run
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/thread_pool/worker.rs:383:5
  73: tokio::runtime::thread_pool::worker::Launch::launch::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/thread_pool/worker.rs:362:45
  74: <tokio::runtime::blocking::task::BlockingTask<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/blocking/task.rs:42:21
  75: tokio::runtime::task::core::CoreStage<T>::poll::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/core.rs:165:17
  76: tokio::loom::std::unsafe_cell::UnsafeCell<T>::with_mut
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/loom/std/unsafe_cell.rs:14:9
  77: tokio::runtime::task::core::CoreStage<T>::poll
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/core.rs:155:13
  78: tokio::runtime::task::harness::poll_future::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/harness.rs:470:19
  79: <core::panic::unwind_safe::AssertUnwindSafe<F> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<()>>::call_once
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/panic/unwind_safe.rs:271:9
  80: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:406:40
  81: <unknown>
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:441:2
  82: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:370:19
  83: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panic.rs:133:14
  84: tokio::runtime::task::harness::poll_future
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/harness.rs:458:18
  85: tokio::runtime::task::harness::Harness<T,S>::poll_inner
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/harness.rs:104:27
  86: tokio::runtime::task::harness::Harness<T,S>::poll
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/harness.rs:57:15
  87: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/raw.rs:144:5
  88: tokio::runtime::task::raw::RawTask::poll
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/raw.rs:84:18
  89: tokio::runtime::task::UnownedTask<S>::run
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/task/mod.rs:413:9
  90: tokio::runtime::blocking::pool::Task::run
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/blocking/pool.rs:91:9
  91: tokio::runtime::blocking::pool::Inner::run
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/blocking/pool.rs:325:17
  92: tokio::runtime::blocking::pool::Spawner::spawn_thread::{{closure}}
             at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/tokio-1.19.2/src/runtime/blocking/pool.rs:300:13
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
   >> Handler list panicked.
   >> This is an application bug.
   >> A panic in Rust must be treated as an exceptional event.
   >> Panicking is not a suitable error handling mechanism.
   >> Unwinding, the result of a panic, is an expensive operation.
   >> Panics will degrade application performance.
   >> Instead of panicking, return `Option` and/or `Result`.
   >> Values of either type can be returned directly from handlers.
   >> A panic is treated as an internal server error.
   >> Outcome: Failure
   >> No 500 catcher registered. Using Rocket default.
   >> Response succeeded.
```

The table define like this:

```
table! {
    bill_record (id) {
        id -> Int8,
        created_time -> Int8,
        updated_time -> Int8,
        deleted -> Int4,
        user_id -> Int8,
        bill_book_id -> Int8,
        remark -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        amount -> Int8,
        bill_book_contents_id -> Int8,
        account_id -> Int4,
    }
}
```

why could not recieve the bigInt result using i64? what should I do to fixed this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html), `sum(amount)` where `amount` is an `int8` is `numeric`.

Comment: how to receive the postgresql numeric data type? @Ry-

Comment: @Dolphin: You specified `<diesel::sql_types::BigInt>`, and need `<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>` instead.

Comment: what data type should I use with the returned data type arrays? `let result = source_query.load::<(f64,i32)>(&get_connection());` @Ry- The f64 could not work as expect, I tried using i64, and did not found the bigdecimal in rust.

Comment: @Dolphin [`PgNumeric`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/pg/data_types/enum.PgNumeric.html) or [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.rs/bigdecimal/latest/bigdecimal/struct.BigDecimal.html), the [implementors of `FromSql<Numeric, Pg>`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/deserialize/trait.FromSql.html)

Comment: I tried PgNumeric, it works, but BigDecimal did not work as expect.